# App crashes after installing app from Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio

So I just uploaded my app to the Google Play Store (in Alpha) for the first time.

But when I install and open the app, it crashes. Yet it works fine if I simply run it through Android Studio.

This is the error that Firebase Crash Reporting says that causes the crash:

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout (CoordinatorLayout.java)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:18793)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5952)
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout (DrawerLayout.java)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:18793)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5952)
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:18793)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5952)
android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1741)
android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:18793)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5952)
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:18793)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5952)
android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1741)
android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1585)
android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1494)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:18793)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5952)
android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:323)
android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:261)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:818)
android.view.View.layout (View.java:18793)
android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:5952)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:2625)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2341)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1493)
```

What could be causing this error? How can I deduce what the problem is when none of my classes are listed in this error?

Comment: have you tried to run a release build from android studio?

Comment: @lelloman How do I run a release build specifically? I'm used to just clicking the green play button.

Comment: on the left in android studio you should see avertical button "Build Variants", you can select the build type there and then run. if you can't find the button, press shift twice quickly and search for "Build Variants"

Comment: Just tried running a release build. It loads the app fine, no crashing. So I'm not sure what the problem is. :/

Comment: by the stacktrace it seems like an unboxing of a null Integer, and it's happening during a layout pass. could you please post the xml layout of the activity that is crashing and your app's module build.gradle?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment. However, I found something else. If I set debugabble to `false` for the release build, the app crashes, but if it's set to `true`, it runs fine. What could this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I'm using Retrofit, along with some POJO model classes. I needed to add the following line to the `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep class package.to.models.** { *; }
```